# How should i tally my opening and closing balance

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hii I'm working on transaction data i have two table in one table data is on daily basis
First table:-

```
gl_cde  txn_dt  txn_id  amount
2104    20140429    10  12750.00
2104    20140429    12  1263.89
2104    20140429    14  793.33
2104    20140429    16  12833.33
```

Second table

```
txn_dte gl_cde  balance
20140424    2104    12791.67  ---Opening balance
20140429    2104    40432.22  ---closing balance
```

I m looking for result

```
Id  gl_cde  Date    Result
1   2104    20140424    12791.67 ---Opening balance
2   2104    20140429    12750
3   2104    20140429    1263.89
4   2104    20140429    793.33
5   2104    20140429    12833.33
6   2104    20140429    40432.22 ---closing balance
```

Actually i'm looking for Opening balance + Sum(amount) from my first table is equal to my closing balance.

I'm not getting how to write query for this in sql server 2012 it is just example bcz for one gl_cde i have multiple date and in first table have multiple gl_cde

Comment: If I get this correctly, you should rather solve this within your presentation layer...

Comment: In the second table, how do you know which is the opening balance and which is the closing balance?  What if there are multiple rows for a given account?

Comment: @GordonLinoff  Actually i m getting opening balance by date what my date before that date

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union all` and `order by`:

```
select row_number() over (partition by gl_cde order by ordering, date),
       gl_cde, date, amount
from ((select gl_cde, Date, Amount, 2 as ordering from t1) union all
      (select gl_cde, Date, balance,
              row_number() over (partition by gl_cde order by date) * 2 - 1
       from t2
      )
     ) tt
order by gl_cde, ordering, date
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff what i m looking i get from yours code....Thanks a lot for yours help...

Answer (score 0):

I woulnd't say this is particularly pretty, and it ***assumes*** that there are only 2 records in the second dataset (with your opening and closing balances). if that's not the case, you need to update your post with more scenarios.

```
WITH VTE1 AS (
    SELECT gl_cde, CONVERT(date, txn_dt) AS txn_dt, txn_id, amount
    FROM (VALUES(2104,'20140429',10,12750.00),
                (2104,'20140429',12,1263.89 ),
                (2104,'20140429',14,793.33  ),
                (2104,'20140429',16,12833.33)) V(gl_cde, txn_dt, txn_id, amount)),
VTE2 AS (
    SELECT CONVERT(date,txn_dte) AS txn_dte, gl_cde, balance
    FROM (VALUES('20140424',2104,12791.67),
                ('20140429',2104,40432.22)) V(txn_dte, gl_cde, balance)),
Combined AS(
    SELECT gl_cde,
           txn_dt,
           amount AS Result,
           txn_id,
           'Transaction' AS DataType
    FROM VTE1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT gl_cde, txn_dte, balance AS result,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY txn_dte) * -1 AS Txn_id,
          'Balance' AS DataType
    FROM VTE2)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY C.txn_dt, CASE txn_id WHEN -1 THEN 'A' WHEN -2 THEN 'C' ELSE 'B' END, txn_id) AS Id,
       gl_cde,
       txn_dt AS [Date],
       Result
FROM Combined C
ORDER BY C.txn_dt, 
         CASE txn_id WHEN -1 THEN 'A' WHEN -2 THEN 'C' ELSE 'B' END,
         txn_id;
```

*I've not included any partitioning in the data here, as we only have the data for one account. you'll need to add the `PARTITION BY` clause with the appropriate columns.*